# Python: List in python turn into a specific format

Tags: python

I have this list of numbers in python

```
['1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '4']
```

And I want to turn it into this format (tuple of int).

```
(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: For information : `(1,1,0)` is a tuple while `[1,1,0]` is a list, it's similar but they have differences explained [here](https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-tuples-vs-lists/) better than I would do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> nums_list = ['1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '4']
>>> nums_tuple = tuple(map(int, nums_list))
>>> nums_tuple
(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4)
```

Or a comprehension:

```
>>> nums_tuple = tuple(int(x) for x in nums_list)
>>> nums_tuple
(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp):

```py
nums_list = ['1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '4']
nums_tuple = tuple([int(x) for x in nums_list])
print(nums_tuple) # (1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the method below

```py
nums_list = ['1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '4']
nums_tuple = tuple(int(x) for x in nums_list)
print(nums_tuple)
```

Comment: use Code Sample please

Answer (score -1):

change list to numpy array of numbers, and store it `my_list = ['1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '4']     my_array = (np.array(my_list,dtype=int))`